# gl_PointCoord undeclared in fragment shader on macOS?

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, glsl, cocos2d-x

I'm using cocos 3.17 on Xcode 11 on Mac.
These are my fragment and vertex shaders.

myShader.frag

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision lowp float;
#define LOWP lowp
#else
#define LOWP
#endif

uniform sampler2D u_texture;
varying LOWP vec4 v_fragmentColor;
uniform mat4 u_rotation;

void main()
{
  mat4 t1= mat4(1);
  mat4 t2= mat4(1);
  t1[3] = vec4(-0.5,-0.5,1,1);
  t2[3] = vec4(+0.5,+0.5,1,1);
  vec2 pos = (t2 * u_rotation * t1 * vec4(gl_PointCoord, 0, 1)).xy;
  gl_FragColor  =  v_fragmentColor * texture2D(u_texture, pos);
}
```

myShader.vert

```
#ifdef GL_ES
#define LOWP lowp
#else
#define LOWP
#endif

attribute vec4 a_position;
uniform float u_pointSize;
uniform LOWP vec4 u_fragmentColor;
varying LOWP vec4 v_fragmentColor;

void main() 
{
  gl_Position     = CC_MVPMatrix * a_position;
  gl_PointSize    = u_pointSize;
  v_fragmentColor = u_fragmentColor;
}
```

When I run it as a Mac app, it gives me this error:

```
cocos2d:
ERROR: 0:36: Use of undeclared identifier 'gl_PointCoord'
ERROR: 0:37: Use of undeclared identifier 'pos'
```

someone can help me to figure out why?

Comment: I'd be *really* wary of tossing around integers like `0` and `1` in un-`#version`'d GLSL hoping that they will automatically be cast to `float`.

Comment: Also, make sure you didn't swap your vert/frag sources by accident, `gl_PointCoord` is a frag-only built-in variable.

Comment: Yes, You're right, I swapped the sources. 
I discovered that the #version 120 directive was missing, if I add it to the beginning of the shader, it gives me an error but because the cocos add empty macros in the initialization. I must pass it as compileTimeHeaders when i call compileShader, I must pass it as compileTimeHeaders when i call compileShader, although I don't know exactly how to do it

Comment: I've just investigated the cocs2d-x api ([`GLProgram`](https://cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.2/dd/d35/classcocos2d_1_1_g_l_program.html) and [`GLProgramState`](https://cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.2/d2/d80/classcocos2d_1_1_g_l_program_state.html)). Sadly I didn't find any relevant information. I seems that cocos2d-x was designed for OpenGL ES 2.0 and cannot deal newer GLSL versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some troubles, I found the solution. 
A GLSL shader that does not have a **#version** directive at the top is assumed to be 1.10, but I really need version 1.2. So, I need to add **'#version 120\n'** as a **compileTimeHeader** string in the initialization:

```
GLProgram *program = new GLProgram();
program->initWithByteArrays(myShader_vert, myShader_frag, "#version 120\n", "");
```

There is a **mistake** in the OpenGL docs which state that **gl_PointCoord** is a 1.1 feature, whereas in fact it was introduced in 1.2.